# AppleScript to focus on a window in Preview app

Tags: window, focus, automator

Im trying to do some manipulation with preview using Automator. I have several windows open in preview, two of which are of interest. One is named "Markup Badges.png" one is called "Screenshot.png"

I want to set the focus to "Screenshot.png", copy the image and close the window, then I want to close the "Markup Badges.png" window.

I am having a lot of trouble getting this to work.

As part of my experimenting I have created two scripts trying to get the windows in focus, so I can then perform additional actions on them

Script 1:

```
on run {input, parameters}

    tell application "Preview"
        set visible of every window whose visible is true to false
    end tel

    tell application "Preview"
        try
            set theWindow to 1st window whose name begins with "Screenshot.png"
            set index of theWindow to 1
            activate
        end try
    end tell

    -- stuff
    delay 1

    tell application "Preview"
        set visible of every window whose visible is false to true
    end tell

    return input
end run
```

Script 2:

```
    on run {input, parameters}

    tell application "Preview"
        set visible of every window whose visible is true to false
    end tell


    tell application "Preview"
        try
            set theWindow to 1st window whose name begins with "Markup Badges.png"
            set index of theWindow to 1
            activate
        end try
    end tell

    -- stuff
    delay 1

    tell application "Preview"
        set visible of every window whose visible is false to true
    end tell
    return input
end run
```

If I run Script 1 on its own, it does what I expect, Screenshot.png window is shown and has focus.

If I run Script 2 on its own, it does what I expect, Markup Badges.png window is shown and has focus.

If I run both scripts (play button in automator, Script 1 runs, followed by script 2) then script 2 does not work as it does on its own. The window is shown, but it does not have focus meaning I cannot send any keypresses to the window.

Any help appreciated

Comment: Posted in error.

Answer (score 0):

I found changing the code to the below fixed the problem.

```
on run {input, parameters}

    tell application "Preview"
        set visible of every window whose visible is true to false
    end tell


    tell application "Preview"
        try
            set theWindow to 1st window whose name begins with "Markup Badges.png"
            set index of theWindow to 1
            activate
            tell application "System Events" to tell process "Preview" to perform action "AXRaise" of window 1
        end try
    end tell

    -- stuff
    delay 1

    tell application "Preview"
        set visible of every window whose visible is false to true
    end tell
    return input
end run
```